# how to join two horizontal arrays-Python

Tags: python, numpy

```
pred=model.predict(validation_X)
```

output generated

```
array([[ 0.26831847,  0.32106167]], dtype=float32)
```

my validation_X is

```
array([ 0.33283483,  0.33283483,  0.32881708,  0.31966644,  0.26327242,
    0.32454859,  0.33233545,  0.25761445])
```

how to join them horizontally??

Comment: Did you try `np.concatenate` or `np.hstack`?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

If you have an `array`:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and a second,

```
b = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
```

you can do:

```
np.concatenate((a, b))
```

to give them joined `horizontally`:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

I think this will do what you want, but I will leave it up to you to incorporate this into your main `code`.